# SharePoint 2013 Save as Template error

Tags: templates, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to save a site as a template (to create new site collections from it) but when I press "Save" I end up with the following error. I have also tried restarting the server and indeed, reinstalling SharePoint (to no avail). Any ideas?

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Feature definition with Id b8455e32-8a67-4c15-9387-b3dd7e01cb4c failed validation, file 'T135PropertyBags\Elements.xml', line 2, character 62: The 'AlwaysCreateFolder' attribute is not declared.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.FeatureXmlValidationCallback.XmlValidationCallBack(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs evtargs)    
 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String arg)    
 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName, String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)    
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()    
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()    
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()    
 at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()    
 at System.Xml.XmlReader.IsStartElement()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.XsdValidateXml(XmlTextReader xmlStreamReader, String friendlyName, String pathXsdFile, String tagExpectedRootNode, Int32 desiredPathVersion, ValidationEventHandler xsdValEventHandler)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.XsdValidateXml(XmlTextReader xmlStreamReader, String friendlyName, String pathXsdFile, String tagExpectedRootNode, ValidationEventHandler xsdValEventHandler)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.SolutionFile.ValidateFeatureXmlFile(String rootTagElement)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureElementsCore(XmlNodeList nodeList, String strFeatureDirRelativeToCabFile, Guid featureId, Dictionary`2 filesAdded)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureElements(XmlNode root, String strFeatureDirRelativeToCabFile, String strFeatureXmlFilename, Guid featureId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.WspSolutionFeature.ProcessFeatureXml()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.InitSolutionFeatures(XmlNode root)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.ProcessSolutionManifest()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.CreateSolutionPackage(SPRequest request, String name, String signature, Byte[] fileBytes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.<>c__DisplayClass4.<AddOrUpgrade>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.AddOrUpgrade(SPListItem item, SPUserSolution existingSolution)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Add(Int32 solutionGalleryItemId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName, String destinationListUrl, Action`1 solutionPostProcessor, Boolean activateSolution)
```

Comment: Did you check this out `AlwaysCreateFolder` in your error code the first line.?

Comment: I cannot do that - I'm simply trying to save the site as a template from inside the SP2013 UI. No code's being touched! It creates the WSP but not before firing up this error. I tried opening the WSP in Visual Studio and removing all AlwaysCreateFolder tags but it hasn't seemed to do the trick either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your 15 hive\TEMPLATE\XML\wss.xsd file contains for `<xs:complexType name="PropertyBagDefinition">`the following attribute:

```
<xs:attribute name="AlwaysCreateFolder" type="TRUEFALSE" use="optional" />
```